# How to take 3 floats and put them in a transform.postion which is a vector3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While I was coding for a tower builder game(like [this one](https://nothke.itch.io/tower)), I needed a way to spawn the tower, so I used Instantiate and for the transform I created a variable called "place" and I tried using the for loop variables for it but it did not work.

Here is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float3 startingLocation;
    Transform place;
    public void SpwanTower(float xx, float yy, float zz, GameObject Brick)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < yy; i++)
        {
            for (int e = 0; e < xx; e++)
            {
                for (int o = 0; o < zz; o++)
                {

                    Instantiate(Brick,place);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public float3 startingLocation;
Transform place;
public void SpwanTower(float xx, float yy, float zz, GameObject Brick)
{
    Vector3 currPos = new Vector3(
        startingLocation.x,
        startingLocation.y,
        startingLocation.z
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < yy; i++)
    {
        for (int e = 0; e < xx; e++)
        {
            for (int o = 0; o < zz; o++)
            {
                //you can change the plus sign to determine to what direction the tower will be built
                currPos.x = startingLocation.x + e;
                currPos.y = startingLocation.y + i;
                currPos.z = startingLocation.z + o;
                Instantiate(Brick, currPos, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OBS: instead of doing `new Vector3(e, i, o)`,
its better to change the x, y, z values of the currPos, since that will executed several times

hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something on the line of:

```
Instantiate(Brick, new Vector3(e, i, o), Quaternion.identity);
```

because you are not using `e`, `i` and `o` variables.

Comment: Probably swap the `yy` and `xx` coordinates to be in their appropriate positions. I realized that's the order the `for` loops are in, but I think the intention is to spawn bricks from the ground up, hence why `yy` for loop is first.

Comment: Yes, most probably. I just maintained the variables' order in the answer but I guess you are right.

Comment: I guess it should rather be `Instantiate(Brick, new Vector3(e, i, o), Quaternion.identity, place);` since according to the description and screenshot it should generate a tower with multiple objects

Comment: Thanks, @derHugo, you are absolutely right. xx, yy, zz are the world's limit, I didn't pay much attention when answering. Edited.

Comment: derHugo i will try when my computer decides to run faster and donw with other stuff :)